# Auto BCC multiple emails

Tags: email

Whenever I send an email I have to BCC my three coworkers, my email auto-populates. Is there any way to include their emails in that field?

Comment: Hi David, welcome to SFSE. Please take a moment to scroll through the [tour] and read [ask]. Could you please **[edit]** your post to clarify how it is related to Salesforce?

Comment: Which platform are you referring to? Pardot? Marketing Cloud? Just an ordinary email from any other Salesforce platform?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are referring to when you send a Send Preview email. The email address that is populated is the email associated to your SFMC login so you would not be able to auto-populate three email addresses.

But if you are referring to at Send time, you can CC or BCC your email addresses.

[image: CC or BCC at send time]

For your case, I would create an alias email to send to the three email addresses and then you can manage the email addresses in that alias outside of SFMC.